# Using ' in Query String

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a query that I want to be able to match strings containing `'`. I currently have:

`QUERY(nameGen!$A$1:$G500, "SELECT D WHERE B matches '"&$B1091&"'",0)`

So it's the cell reference `&$B1091&` that will contain the string

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Needed to wrap the cell ref in 3 lots of `"`. So now its:

`QUERY(nameGen!$A$1:$G500, "SELECT D WHERE B matches """&$B1091&"""",0)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternate option is to use;

"string 1"&char(34)&"string2".

Edit; looks like Google sheets uses char(39) - mssql uses char(39) to quote strings, Excel / vba uses char(34).

For other special characters if applicable check an ASCII table...